# Importing Text File in Java Constructor

Tags: java

I am not sure where the problems is spawning from. I have two classes, one called testFriends class and another called GUIapp class. In each of the classes, my object is to import the file for use. In the testFriends class, I import the file in the main method, it parses it and everything works nicely. In my GUIapp class, I tried doing the same thing, but importing it in the constructor method and it tells me the file doesn't exists. Both of the files classes reside in the same src folder and I am using:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
```

where the inputFile is just a string "friends.txt".

Here are the two classes:

```
//This class works

public class temp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    try {
        System.out.println("hey");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("friends.txt"));  //create string buffer for reading
        String line = in.readLine(); //reading first line
        System.out.println(line);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Fail Import.");
    }

}

}


//////////The one below doesn't...

public class GUIapp extends JApplet{
//** PANEL **//
private JPanel outerPanel;

//** Button **//
private JButton button1;


/*
 * Constructor for Getting all the friends set up
 */
public GUIapp() throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("friends.txt"));//Error Line

}

/*
 * Create Stuff
 */
public void createStuff() {
    outerPanel = new JPanel(); //create outer panel
    button1 = new JButton("Click Me");
    outerPanel.add(button1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}


/*
 * Initialize Stuff
 */
public void init(){
    createStuff(); //initialize create stuff
    this.add (outerPanel); 
}


}
```

Any ideas why when both are working in the same directory, one can read while the other can't?

Thanks,

EDIT: Below is the exception thrown when I run the GUIapp Class:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: friends.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
at GUIapp.<init>(GUIapp.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:807)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:714)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:368)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Please specify how/where you're launching the applet.  Depending on your answer, you may want to read [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).

Comment: This is my first time doing GUI design. I am initializing the applet through the "init" method, which calls the createStuff method.

Comment: No, I mean using what tool are you using to launch the applet?  If you're viewing it in a browser, definitely check out that link I mentioned above.  You may want to check it out anyway.

Comment: Compate the 'current classpath' in both cases if they are the same.

Comment: Currently, when i run the code, a applet just pops up. I am not sure what you mean by tool, but no not using a browser.

Comment: if ur app throws exception, tell us please

Comment: Just edited the question which now includes the exception. Thanks everyone!

Comment: try `in.close()` in the end of the constructor

Comment: I found the problem, Francesco was right in that the class path differed for some reason. Ill google how I can change that. Thanks so much guys.

Comment: @user1234440 you can read the file using `scanner` it is very easier, if you want i can give you a working example

Comment: Thanks Francesco, I actually have an entire class for reading files already written.

Comment: @user1234440 i just update my post

Comment: @user1234440 Applets are suppose to deployed via networks/servers and typically viwed within browsers.  If you want to run a desktop application, you're better of using something like `JFrame` instead.  Apart from everything else, it has it's own window and doesn't suffer from the same security concerns that applets do.  You may also find, if the applet is been displayed in the applet view, that your main method isn't been executed (the applet viewer will load the applet directly)

Answer (score 1):

At the run time your applet doesn't have the file your are looking for. Make sure that the file is present at the run time.

please add this method to your code so that you can get the file

```
public void readFile(String fileToRead){
  String line;
  URL url = null;
  try{
  url = new URL(getCodeBase(), fileToRead);
  }
  catch(MalformedURLException e){}

  try{
  InputStream in = url.openStream();
  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

  // your business logic here
  }
  catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

/*
 * Constructor for Getting all the friends set up
 */

```
public GUIapp() throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException{
    readFile("friends.txt")
}
```

for more details look at this images from Javase
[image]

To create an Image object that uses the a.gif image file under imgDir, the applet can use the following code:

```
Image image = getImage(getCodeBase(), "imgDir/a.gif");
```

Comment: The file is present, its just that one can read while another can't.

Comment: an applet acts in another way. there is a difference between the both

Comment: @user1234440 this is what i'am saying java.io.FileNotFoundException: friends.txt (No such file or directory)